# Renpy Clock skip time button

Tags: function, button, renpy

I am trying to create a textbutton when clicked will advance time on a simple clock.

In my script.rpy file I have.

```
label start:

    show screen timeclock #shows time & day on screen
    return
```

I then created a clock.rpy file for my clock screen and logic.

```
define day = 1
define clock = 7


# Display Time and Day
screen timeclock():
    vbox:
        xpos 0.0
        yalign 0.0

        text _("Time: [clock]:00") size 40
        text _("Day: [day]") size 30
        textbutton _("Wait 1-Hour"):
            action Null   #<<< This needs to be correctTime
            text_size 10


correctTime:  #<<< This needs to be button action
    if clock <= 22:
        $clock += 1
    else:
        $clock = 0
        $day += 1
```

How can I make the textbutton on click do correctTime logic?   Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
Clock.rpy

```
define day = 1
define clock = 7


# Display Time and Day
screen timeclock():
    vbox:
        xpos 0.0
        yalign 0.0

        text _("Time: [clock]:00") size 40
        text _("Day: [day]") size 30
        textbutton _("Wait 1-Hour"):
            action Function(correctTime)
            text_size 10

init python:
    def correctTime():
        global day
        global clock
        if clock <= 22:
            clock += 1
        else:
            clock = 0
            day += 1
```